# firestore database receive the previous document not the current one?

Tags: firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-redux-firebase

I am using firebase authentication in react and redux project, and i am facing a strange beahavior in cloud firestore, the document sent to it is always the previous one not the current one:

When i sign up for the first time from a browser that i did never signed up from , the database receives the right document(the current one), but if i tried to sign up again from the same browser, I am facing that problem

This is my redux **signUp** action

```
export const signUp = ({ email, password, firstName, lastName }) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((resp) => {
                return firestore.collection('users').doc(resp.user.uid).set({
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    initials: firstName[0] + lastName[0]
                });
            })
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS' });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'SIGNUP_ERROR', err });
            });
    };

}
```

This is my **firebase config** file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const fbConfig = {
    apiKey: "some key",
    authDomain: "react-redux-firebase-b4759.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://react-redux-firebase-b4759.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "react-redux-firebase-b479",
    storageBucket: "react-redux-firebase-b479.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "657030244",
    appId: "some id",
    measurementId: "G-Y3VR"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);
  firebase.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

  export default firebase;
```

and this is my **index.js** file

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
    reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)
  )
);

const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
  attachAuthIsReady: true
};

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance,
  presence: 'presence',
  sessions: 'sessions'
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
          <App />
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Do you have a signoff action? If so, can you share it? and also, if you do have, are you performing an `unsubscribe()` of firebase? This could be a part of the issue.

Comment: @ralemos yes, i have a signUp action and it is in the question, didn'y you see it?? and no how to unsubscribe of firebase?

Comment: Yes, I saw that you have a signUp action, for some reason I misread and thought it was a signIn (were user already exists), anyway, how do you populate this variable `resp.user.uid`? If this is still hanging on to the previous value, you will get the previous document as a result.

Comment: Did the comment above helped you solve the issue? If so, I will write it into an actual answer.